# How to set up conversation logic in game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, logic, artificial-intelligence

I am making a game where in one part of it the player have to take part in conversation. The game asks player a `question` and gives `3 options` to answer. When player answers, a new question pops up, according to player's previous answer. It means, that there are `3` possible potential questions now. Each of these questions brings 3 new answers, so there 9 potential `answers` now. And each answer leads to a question again, so there are `9 questions` and `27` potential `answers` now and so on and so on...

I don't ask for solution, but an idea of how to set it up will be very appreciated. I just don't know how to organize it properly. How usually developers do it in their games?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to **Duncan C** for the idea. What I have done to solve the problem is just a plist with dictionary which contains a lot of small dictionaries inside. Each small dictionary - a question with possible answers and unique ID. I made an example of my model:

```
<key>q1</key>
<dict>

<key>question</key>
<string>Do you want to go left, right or straight?</string>

<key>a1</key>
<string>Left.</string>

<key>a2</key>
<string>Right.</string>

<key>a3</key>
<string>Straight.</string>

<key>a1key</key>
<string>q2.0</string>

<key>a2key</key>
<string>q2.1</string>

<key>a3key</key>
<string>q2.2</string>

</dict>


<key>q2.0</key>
<dict>

<key>question</key>
<string>You went left and found the key.</string>

<key>a1</key>
<string>Take the key.</string>

<key>a2</key>
<string>Go forward.</string>

<key>a3</key>
<string>Go back.</string>

<key>a1key</key>
<string>q2.01</string>

<key>a2key</key>
<string>q2.02</string>

<key>a3key</key>
<string>q2.03</string>

</dict>




<key>q2.1</key>
<dict>

<key>question</key>
<string>You went right and met a monster.</string>

<key>a1</key>
<string>Fight it.</string>

<key>a2</key>
<string>Run away.</string>

<key>a3</key>
<string>Hide from it.</string>

<key>a1key</key>
<string>q2.11</string>

<key>a2key</key>
<string>q2.12</string>

<key>a3key</key>
<string>q2.13</string>

</dict>


<key>q2.2</key>
<dict>

<key>question</key>
<string>You went straight and found a castle!</string>

<key>a1</key>
<string>Enter it.</string>

<key>a2</key>
<string>Continue going straight without visiting the castle.</string>

<key>a3</key>
<string>Go back.</string>

<key>a1key</key>
<string>q2.21</string>

<key>a2key</key>
<string>q2.22</string>

<key>a3key</key>
<string>q2.23</string>

</dict>
```

And so on and so on. So each time player chooses one of the option, a next linked dictionary comes up. I think it works really well and its possible to use same question to link between each other, so its not necessary to rewrite same things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a plist rather than XML. Plists are easier to create and easier to read.

In either case though, putting your questions and answers into an external file makes your program flexible, without much effort. Then, if you decide later you want to have 50 questions, you just add records to your file.

I would suggest an array of dictionaries. You could create it like this:

```
#define K_QUESTION_KEY @"question"
#define K_ANSWERS_KEY @"answers"
#define K_CORRECT_ANSWER_INDEX @"answerIndex"


NSArray *questions = @[
  @{K_QUESTION_KEY: @"What is your quest",
    K_ANSWERS_KEY: @[@"I seek truth and enlightenment", 
                     @"I seek to escape from reality",
                     @"I seek the Holy Grail"];
   K_CORRECT_ANSWER_INDEX: @(2)
   },
  @{K_QUESTION_KEY: @"What is your favorite color",
    K_ANSWERS_KEY: @[@"Blue", 
                     @"Red",
                     @"Blue - no, green!"];
   K_CORRECT_ANSWER_INDEX: @(1)
   },
  @{K_QUESTION_KEY: @"What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow",
    K_ANSWERS_KEY: @[@"42", 
                     @"I don't know",
                     @"A European or African swallow?"];
   K_CORRECT_ANSWER_INDEX: @(2)
   }

];
```

Then write it to disk using

```
[questions writeToFile: file_path atomically: YES];
```

Then you'd use similar syntax to read the file and traverse through it.

Comment: Thank you, @Duncan C, but what if I have no correct answers in the talk but each question just leads to a new set of 3 different answers? So it looks like a "tree" model.

Comment: Well then, instead of a "correct" answer for each dictionary, have an array of answers, and a second array using the same indexes that contains another question dictionary for each possible answer. You can nest such questions as deep as you would like.

Comment: If your questions are ever used in more than one place you might want to instead go to a flat structure where you only have a single array of questions, but there is a unique "Question ID" field for each question. Then, in the array of answers for each question you could include the question ID to link to if the user picks that answer. You could then use the NSArray method indexOfObjectPassingTest to find the question with that ID.

Comment: Thanks. I made an almost same solution. Please, check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

i have not try it but here is my suggestion :

```
<qa>
<question_1 question="what is your name ?">
<option value="mikel"  />
<option value="john"  />
<option value="sosan"  />
</question_1>

<mikel value="what is the biggest thing in the word ?">
<option value="thing1" isTrue="false"/>
<option value="thing2" isTrue="false"/>
<option value="thing3" isTrue="true"/>
</mikel >

....
<!--and for other answers -->

<thing1 value="what is the biggest thing in the word ?">
<option value="thing11" isTrue="false"/>
<option value="thing22" isTrue="false"/>
<option value="thing33" isTrue="true"/>
</thing1>
... so on
</qa>
```

if you used the xml , then you can even use any other file for the same app .other questions  .

hope this  help you ,goodluck !

Comment: Interesting solution. I guess, I need to learn how to use XML in iOS app. Thank you.